# What is the behavior of null/empty value in compound shard key?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

> I have a shard key based on **{Field1:1,Field2:1}** where **Field2 can
>   be null**. So if two documents have **same value for Field1 and
>   null/empty value of Field2** then are they considered to **belong to
>   the same shard key/non split-able**??